# Invalid cast exception C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting

```
foreach(Label l in Controls)    // setting all labels' s visbility  on page to true
     l.Visible =true;
```

But on running ,i am getting following error

`Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.admin_master' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the set **all** labels on the page to visible you need a recursive function.

```
private void SetVisibility<T>(Control parent, bool isVisible)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
    {
        if(ctrl is T)
            ctrl.Visible = isVisible;
        SetVisibility<T>(ctrl, isVisible);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SetVisibility<Label>(Page, true);
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir He did say "setting all labels' s visbility on page to true" in the question.

Comment: an extra check can be added ( hasControls) see my answer. :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Doesn't matter since it wont enter the for loop of there is no children.

Comment: It _does_ matter - you are openning a new instance of recursion.  why to send it to a function if it doesnt have childs ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I mean its not wrong to add the check, but it would not have any measurable performance impact.

Comment: @Magnus function template just made my work easier. +1 for this

Comment: @Magnus In a similar way i tried setting `ReadOnly` property but `System.Web.UI.Control ` does not have definition for that . is there  any other way ?

Comment: @kushal `ReadOnly` on which type of control?

Comment: @kushal If you add `where T : TextBox` it should work, like: `private void SetReadOnly<T>(Control parent, bool isReadOnly) where T : TextBox`. And than cast `ctrl` to `T`

Comment: @Magnus Why i have to cast in this case ?

Comment: Because ctrl is of type `Control`.

Answer (score 5):

If one of the controls is not of type label, you'll get that error.

You could try:

```
foreach(Label l in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    l.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: `"If one of the controls is not of type label, you'll get that error."` It means if i am having other controls like textbox and button on same page then i should use it ..ryt ? Please correct me if i am wrong . And this code is not working .

Comment: This code require at least .Net 3.5 and that you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your codefile. Other then that it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the current "l" has the required destination type:

```
foreach(control l in Controls) {
    if(l is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)
        l.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Control l in Controls)    
        if (l is Label)    l.Visible =true;
```

if you want in all hierarchy :

```
  public static void SetAllControls( Type t, Control parent /* can be Page */)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == t) c.Visible=true;
            if (c.HasControls())  GetAllControls( t, c);
        }

    }

 SetAllControls( typeof(Label), this);
```

Comment: @kushal main labels _will_ be visible ! do you want all the labels in page ? ( in all hierarchy ? )

Comment: ryt now i am working on a simple web form having nine labels . Hierarchy will be same for all .

Comment: You need to remove the `controls =`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Search(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
                Search(c);
            if (c is Label)
                c.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

and

```
Search(this.Page);
```